# UTF-8 with or without BOM?

Tags: html, css, encoding

When you write web pages nowadays and you use UTF-8, what is the best
practice - to encode your pages as UTF-8 with or without BOM?

Then... what's the answer for any type of file,
not just for web pages (i.e. not just for HTML files)?

Comment: @CPUTerminator "but to signify the start of a UTF stream" >>> Well, yes, I was thinking just in that direction i.e. just for that purpose.

Answer (score 5):

From the Unicode [website](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom5):

> Q: Can a UTF-8 data stream contain the BOM character (in UTF-8 form)? If yes, then can I still assume the remaining UTF-8 bytes are in big-endian order?
>
> A: Yes, UTF-8 can contain a BOM. However, it makes no difference as to the endianness of the byte stream. UTF-8 always has the same byte order. An initial BOM is only used as a signature — an indication that an otherwise unmarked text file is in UTF-8. Note that some recipients of UTF-8 encoded data do not expect a BOM. Where UTF-8 is used transparently in 8-bit environments, the use of a BOM will interfere with any protocol or file format that expects specific ASCII characters at the beginning, such as the use of "#!" of at the beginning of Unix shell scripts.

as well as:

> Where the data has an associated type, such as a field in a database, a BOM is unnecessary. In particular, if a text data stream is marked as UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE or UTF-32LE, a BOM is neither necessary nor permitted. Any U+FEFF would be interpreted as a ZWNBSP.

A BOM is not required nor recommended with use in UTF-8 as it serves no purpose except to mark the start of a UTF-8 stream. This however isn't an effective way to distinguish UTF-8 as the BOM may simply be parsed as characters in other encoding formats.

A BOM should only be used in the context that data is transmitted in a multi-byte format (UTF-16/32) with no specification of endianness. Where you would use something like this is beyond me but that stands as the only case where BOM is necessary.

Distinguish text encoding either within the file (HTML meta tag and so forth) or better, in the code that will generate and use said text files. For wide distribution of UTF-8 files, the more common variant is the one without BOM. In fact, some text editors do not expect the BOM and may fail to parse the stream properly.

Comment: Thanks for this pretty detailed and authoritative answer.